# Даны два слова. Вывести на экран те буквы слов, которые встречаются в обоих словах только один раз

Tags: python

Даны два слова. Вывести на экран те буквы слов, которые встречаются в обоих словах только один раз. Например, если заданные слова `процессор` и `информация`, то ответом должно быть: `п е н ф м а я`.

заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста, что вы пробовали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы разбил эти слова на 2 списка(списки желательно сделать двусвязными, что бы было менее затратно удалять элементы из середины(при больших входных данных удаление из середины обычного списка поглощает много памяти)):

```py
from collections import deque
l = deque()                  # реализует двусвязный граф(очередь)
                             # имеется возможность удалить N-ый элемент как справа(l.pop()),
                             # так и слева(l.leftpop())
```

Далее пройдёмся по 2 этим спискам, и удалим повторяющиеся элементы(как в слове *проце**сс**ор*)
Потом просто запускаешь 2 вложенных цикла, проверяешь есть ли 1 элемент в другом списке:

- Если нет, то добавляешь этот элемент в новый список *ans*, который в конце необходимо просто вывести
- Если оно есть во 2-м списке, то пишем *break*, и выходим из вложенного списка, запуская след круг первого списка.

Ну, кажется, всё)
Да и советую познакомиться с модулем *collections*,  если вы с ним ещё не знакомы, так как он **иногда** очень помогает в работе, облегчая код и уменьшая время выполнения программы.   Удачи

Comment: Не очень понятно, на кой тут нужны связные списки и деки, тем более что Вы знаете про модуль collections, в котором есть подходящая структура данных, эффективная для данной задачи

Comment: не проще через set?

Comment: @finally, Я не представляю, как его использовать тут. Не подскажите как?

Answer (score 0):

Группируем и считаем количество в группах

```
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np

x = 'процессор' + 'информация'
new_x = ''
for el,g in groupby(sorted(x)):
    if len(list(g)) == 1:
        new_x += el + ' '

print(new_x)
```